# ORA -00333: redo log read error (Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 on Linux RedHat)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Backstory: We had to roll our test server back a couple months because of bad testing.  We chose the last complete backup before the testing had started. Now that it's rolled back, I can't get the database to cooperate.

When I try to log into sqlplus, I get ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress.

Following one solution, I was able to use connect / as sysdba

status from v$instance; was MOUNTED

shutdown immediate; worked

startup; returned database mounted. ORA-00333: redo log read error block ###### count ####

When I look in the alert_*.log I see:

```
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id ########
Database mounted in Exlcusive Mode
Lost write protection disabled
Completed: ALTER DATABASE MOUNT
Thu Mar 01 15:41:02 2018
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
Beginning crash recovery of 1 threads
Started redo scan
Incomplete read from log member '/redacted/REDACTED/onlinelog/o1_mf_2_blahblah_.log'.
Trying next member.
Aborting crash recovery due to error 333
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/redacted/redacted/trace/redacted_ora_31209.trc:
ORA-00333: redo log red error block ###### count ####
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/redacted/redacted/trace/redacted_ora_31209.trc:
ORA-00333: redo log red error block ###### count ####
ORA-333 signaled during: ALTER DATABASE OPEN...
```

Following suggestions for that error, I queried the status of the log file group and found that 1 and 3 are INACTIVE, 2 is CURRENT.

I saw some suggestions to recover the database using backup controlfile, then feeding it the path to the CURRENT redo log, and then ALTER to OPEN.  But, all of the examples show redo1 being current, and last time I did that when 2 was current, it seemed to throw even more errors and sqlplus became even more uncooperative (I think it didn't even let me connect as sysdba anymore).  I don't want to try that again except as an absolute last resort.

Another suggestion said to do an incomplete recovery, but didn't give instructions.  Besides that, we *just* rolled this whole machine back to a backup version.

What other things can I check/try?

Comment: When you say "We chose the last complete backup before the testing had started" - is that a database backup, or an OS level backup of the machine?  That kind of error is the kind of thing you typically see when a OS level image is taken without the database being aware of it (ie, either shutdown or in backup mode or similar)

Comment: It was the whole machine. We do cold backups. I want to say that the database is down while the image is copied, but it may only be the overlying application that is down. Either way, it's what the application vendor recommended. (I'll have to double-check that when I get a chance.)

Comment: If the database was up during that OS backup, then after restoration its basically a mess because it is no longer point-in-time consistent (ie, the first files were backed up earlier than the last files).  I think you're gonna have trouble here because it sounds like you don't have a means of getting that consistency back